# How do I make my discord bot (Discord.js v14.9.0) shutdown, while it's using PM2

Tags: process, discord.js, pm2, shutdown

I am trying to make a kill switch for my Discord Bot that uses PM2 to keep it running.
After I use the command, PM2 just restarts the bot.
How do I kill the process until I restart it manually? [What it shows when I run `pm2 list`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Was.png)

Code in my command file:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
let path = require("path");
let batch = path.resolve("TerminateProcess.bat");
    await exec(batch, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
});
```

TerminateProcess.bat file:

```
pm2 stop index.js
```

After I use the command, PM2 just restarts the bot.
How do I kill the process until I restart it manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 stop ID
```

is correct. But your ID/name is probably wrong. use `pm2 list` to see what the ID and name is of your bot. Then use either one of those (It's probably a number for ID, and "index" for name.) So from your screenshot you can use: "1" or "index". Of course, better make sure that your .bat command file is being ran as well. Check you console output for that, you might just as well be crashing the bot because you have the wrong path.

Here's an example that is valid as long as the files are in the same folder:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
await exec("./TerminateProcess.bat", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   if (error !== null) {
     console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
 }
});
```

path.resolve() is not going to find the location of the bat file for you if you haven't inputted it correctly.